# App installation, rendering html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iframe, bigcommerce

When I'm trying to get user credentials using this scheme provided ( https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/callback ). I run up in rather strange behaviour. When I need to send back for you GET response, your installation stucks on "Loading..." page. So how do I provide user with some form? Because it's told that this is used to make:

"Bigcommerce renders this in an iframe inside of the Control Panel. It could be a form that collects further information from the user or you could redirect the user to the main page of your app."

But I can't make this happen, because your platform just doesn't show up my html or any of the redirects I make (and it doesn't meter to which page I make redirect, to my or facebook etc.) it still stucks in it. !!!And by stuck I mean, that page stops loading, and just stays title -> "Loading...".

I use Ruby on Rails, and whats strange, that if I make some kind of error, then it shows up in your iframe. But neither render 'myview' nor redirect_to 'page' works.
I will provide some screenshots.

This is when I try to render some view or just redirect to url:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/275730/1845802/lbM5coQHI8dAsrp/Screen%20Shot%202015-03-07%20at%2013.26.43.png
And this is when I on purpose make an error:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/275730/1845802/1In7kpAefyaq4X0/Screen%20Shot%202015-03-07%20at%2013.27.03.png